# Vim - Performing substitution on certain lines only

Tags: vim, substitution

I have found the following in my quest to perform a substitution on even numbered lines only:

```
:g/^/if !(line('.')%2)|s/foo/bar/g|endif
```

Works great. But can someone please explain the need for the | characters in the command section of the :g call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|` character is the *command separator*; with it, you can concatenate multiple Ex commands in a single line, without adding newlines. See [`:help :bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3abar).

So, your conditional is equivalent to the following:

```
if !(line('.')%2)
    s/foo/bar/g
endif
```

Note that some Ex commands consume the entire remainder of the command-line and therefore cannot be directly concatenated with `|`. But you can wrap those commands in `:execute "{cmd}"`.

Comment: Thanks. I think the bars within the if construct confused me a bit there, but makes sense now.