# Can't map <Leader>z to <C-W>|<C-W>_ in vim

Tags: vim

I tried to add the following line in my `vimrc`

```
nnoremap <Leader>z <C-w>|<C-w>_
```

But when vim starts up, it gives me an error:

> E488: Trailing characters: _

Then I tried to change the sequence of my commands, so I changed the mapping to:

```
nnoremap <Leader>z <C-W>_<C-W>|
```

There are no errors after this change, but it did not behave as I want to. What I want is to hit `<Leader>z` then other split windows would be minimized.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679200/vim-performing-substitution-on-certain-lines-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `|`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>z <C-w>\|<C-w>_
```

A pipe usually separates lines.